# 18.04: GRUB restart looping

Tags: 18.04, grub2, dell, restart

```
PC: Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming
Proc: Intel i7-????  4-core
GPU: Nvidia GTX 1060Ti
```

I have fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.4. My PC keeps restarting after picking Ubuntu in [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html).

How can I solve this issue ?

PS: Ubuntu is my only OS on this PC, so why do I have GRUB?

Comment: You must have a bootloader, and GRUB is standard. The bootloader was stuck in the MBR with legacy partition tables, and goes in /boot/efi/ with GPT partition tables. https://askubuntu.com/a/749414/197910 and https://askubuntu.com/a/961091/197910 shows more.

Comment: in the grub menu, select the recovery mode and find out the detailed error message why it failed to boot.

Comment: recovery mod also restart

Comment: it seems i have bios issues, is there a way to install ubuntu while uefi and secure boot enabled? because kernel could not load, i disabled secure boot and that worked. But the problems I have is because my pc has bios issues with that, so I think installing when secure boot enabled will solve it, is there a way?